# how to make connection string for the built in database in C#

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am using builtin database in C# Windows app. Now my app is completed.

I am using the following connection string;

```
<add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\practiseofcsharp\ager\ager\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
```

This is working fine but now I want to import this application. How do I get rid of this complete path? I just want to use the name of the database.

Comment: <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\practiseofcsharp\ager\ager\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />   this is the connection string that i am using but i want get rid of this complete path.

Comment: How to you plan to use SQL Server or does your application even use SQL server?

Comment: sir i am using .mdf database. now i have change my connection string to this . <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />-->
    <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>. and my code do not giving me error. but when i check the database it not showing any data.

Comment: no there is no error while inserting data. but when ever i check the table it is empty. but if write the full path this code insert data ... please help me

Comment: LocalDB is for testing and development in your local machine. You will need to connect to a real SQL database, when you go for staging and production.

Comment: ok, sir thanks for your guidance. I will do this. actually I was making a demo application in which I need to active the product app with on line product key here I made a little database so I use this builtin database. thanks sir again